# Is it possible to listen for apple in app purchase transactions from a server?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, storekit

I want to be able to get a message about the transaction status in the backend from apple when someone attempts a purchase. Is this possible?
I’ve been looking for something like this in the in app purchases docs but I can’t seem to find

Comment: Not when they *attempt* a purchase, but for certain other events, particularly subscription events https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/app_store_server_notifications_v2

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can get the real time status updation from apple.

Follow this [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/) here they talk about server to server notification service

Comment: They don’t fire updates when purchases happens. That’s precisely what I’m looking for